# Strange happenings with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Here is a very simple program

```
for i in range(4):
    print(f'i = {i}')
for i in range(4):
    print(f'i cubed = {i*i*i}')
print('Auf Wiedersehen')
```

It's called test2.py and runs in a virtual environment called "envo"

And here is what appears on the console when I run it:

> (envo) D:\py_new\bom>python test2.py

> i = 0

> i = 1

> i = 2

> i = 3

> i cubed = 0

> i cubed = 1

> i cubed = 8

> i cubed = 27

> Auf Wiedersehen

> (envo) D:\py_new\bom>

Here is a slightly modified version of the same problem. I import numpy

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(4):
    print(f'i = {i}')
for i in range(4):
    print(f'i cubed = {i*i*i}')
print('Auf Wiedersehen')
```

The only difference is the statement "import numpy as np"

And here is what now appears on the console:

> (envo) D:\py_new\bom>python test2.py

> hello world

> goodbye world

> i = 0

> i = 1

> i = 2

> i = 3

> i cubed = 0

> i cubed = 1

> i cubed = 8

> i cubed = 27

> Auf Wiedersehen

> (envo) D:\py_new\bom>

The "hello world" and "goodbye world" now appear on top.

The statements that printed these words were in a previous program called test1.py

This effect persists even after rebooting my computer.

Here is an even simpler program, test3.py

```
import numpy as np
```

And here is what appears on the console

> (envo) D:\py_new\bom>python test3.py

> hello world

> goodbye world

> (envo) D:\py_new\bom>

I am a moderately experienced user of numpy and pandas and have never encountered anything like this.

The operating system is Windows 10 pro

I even did a complete redo of my virtual environment to get rid of this effect. It persists.

Please help

Comment: DId you save a file named `numpy.py` in your current working directory?

Comment: What does `print(numpy.__file__)` show you? I suspect you have some script named `numpy.py` somewhere. What about `import os; print(os.listdir())` give you?

Comment: Bingo. And now I feel like an imbecile. But thanks